# Add FileName in ListView

Tags: c#, list, file, listview

Consider that in Folder xxx I have 3 files and I want to return the names of those 3 file in a `ListView`.
My updater function runs every second, which means that the `ListView` items must always be updated with the new files.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DirectoryInfo` class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss(v=vs.110).aspx

You should call the `GetFiles()` method, which will return a list with the file names presented in the directory.